# Finding all paths in graph Python

Tags: python, algorithm, graph

I have adjacency matrix of some graph. I know nothing about how this graph looks like, it depends from starts conditions. It could be directed or undirected, cyclic, etc.
So, I need to find all paths between all vertices.

[Graph example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnNft.png)

For example, in this particullar graph we have

```
2 0 3
2 1 3
2 0 1 3
0 2 1 3
0 1 3
1 3
```

I know about DFS or BFS, but don't know how to implement them in this task.

Comment: if you have `1 3`, why not all the other vertices as well?

Comment: also, what's specifically your issue?

Comment: Graph algorithms have been studied for a very long time. I suggest that you google "graph finding all paths" or something along those lines to find content online that will help you understand how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you've defined the adjacency matrix for this graph as

```
adj_matrix = [[0, 1, 1, 1],
              [0, 0, 0, 1],
              [1, 1, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

in that case, a recursive depth-first search for every path would work like this:

```
def iter_paths(adj, min_length=2, path=None):
    # different paths for starting and recurring
    # you could use two different methods, the first calling the second and 
    #   the second calling itself, if you wanted
    if not path:
        for start_node in range(len(adj)):
            yield from iter_paths(adj, min_length, [start_node])
    else:
        # yield a path as soon as we first encounter it
        if len(path) >= min_length:
            yield path
        # if we encounter a cycle (current location has been visited before)
        # then don't continue to recur
        if path[-1] in path[:-1]:  
            return
        # search for all paths forward from the current node, recursively
        current_node = path[-1]
        for next_node in range(len(adj[current_node])):
            if adj[current_node][next_node] == 1:
                yield from iter_paths(adj, min_length, path + [next_node])

print(list(iter_paths(adj_matrix)))
```

This produces the following list of paths:

```
[[0, 1],
 [0, 1, 3],
 [0, 2],
 [0, 2, 0],
 [0, 2, 1],
 [0, 2, 1, 3],
 [0, 3],
 [1, 3],
 [2, 0],
 [2, 0, 1],
 [2, 0, 1, 3],
 [2, 0, 2],
 [2, 0, 3],
 [2, 1],
 [2, 1, 3]]
```

---

A breadth-first algorithm would be very similar to a depth-first algorithm - except that, instead of using recursion, it would essentially keep a running list of `path`s that have been visited, and when a depth-first algorithm would call itself the breadth-first algorithm would simply add the new path to the list. It would iterate in a `while` loop until it reached the end of that list, then return the full list.

This only changes the order in which we examine nodes, in this case - you'll note that the depth-first search arranges them "alphabetically", whereas a breadth-first search would arrange them in ascending order of length.

Comment: I can't find exactly where the error is in your code, but my compiler (VS 2019) and online compilers get the same error RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison. This error occurs on the matrix that you used in your example. Other matrices have the same error.
P.S. the last line of your code is missing a closing parenthesis ')'

Comment: @OlehChaika Fixed, sorry. Forgot to pass `min_length` into the recursive call. Try again, if you would, and it should work now.